# Variable not defined in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am fetching data from php file using Ajax .
I am able to see fetched data in console but whenever I am trying to print variable in response , it is showing undefined !
console data ----

```
Object { 
        draw: 0, 
        recordsTotal: 1, 
        recordsFiltered: 1, 
        data: (1) […], 
        input: [] 
}
```

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
funBroadcast();
function funBroadcast()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/afk/temp.php",
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert(data['recordsFiltered']);//undefined value
            if(data['recordsFiltered']==1){
               
                swal({
                    title:"Achhasa Title hai ",
                    text:"Hello Bhai kaise ho ?",
                    type:'success',
                    icon: "success",
                    confirmButtonText:' Ok! ',
                    width: '650px'
                    }).then((result) => {  
                       
                    });

            }    
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    var errorMsg = 'Ajax request failed: ' + xhr.responseText;
                    alert(errorMsg);
            
          }
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks , it is working now !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dataType: "JSON",` to the AJAX Call, then jQuery will convert the JSONString returned in `data` to a javascript object for you automagically

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
funBroadcast();
function funBroadcast()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/afk/temp.php",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',       // <<-- CODE ADDED HERE
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert(data['recordsFiltered']);//undefined value
            if(data['recordsFiltered']==1){
               
                swal({
                    title:"Achhasa Title hai ",
                    text:"Hello Bhai kaise ho ?",
                    type:'success',
                    icon: "success",
                    confirmButtonText:' Ok! ',
                    width: '650px'
                    }).then((result) => {  
                       
                    });

            }    
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    var errorMsg = 'Ajax request failed: ' + xhr.responseText;
                    alert(errorMsg);
            
          }
    });
}

</script>
```